# Test Results exersise

Tags: c++, c++11

Exercise: Test results are saved in a text file as below. The first line indicates the maximum
scoring for individual tasks. Each subsequent line contains the student's one-part surname and
points gained by him for subsequent tasks. The number of assignments or students is not known in advance. Write program
"Test" , which takes the name of such a file as an argument and prints to standard
output the combined results of each student and the average results of each assignment as in the example
below. The program only includes the **fstream, iostream, sstream, string and vector** header files.

```
Sample input file input.txt
                 5.0 5.0 5.0
Einstein         1.5 3.0 0.5
Chopin           0.5 3.5 2.5
Sklodowska-Curie 5.0 5.0 5.0
```

```
Sample implementation:

Linux: ./colloquium input.txt
Windows: colloquium.exe input.txt
Out: Einstein 5
Out: Chopin 6.5
Out: Sklodowska-Curie 15
Out: 1 2.33333
Out: 2 3.83333
Out: 3 2.66667
```

This is what I have done so far :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
std::ifstream input(argv[1]);
double sum = 0.;
for (std::string line; std::getline(input, line);)
    {
    std::string word;
    for (std::istringstream stream(line); stream >> word;);
    double grade;
    std::cout<<line<<std::endl;
        if (std::istringstream(word) >> grade)
        {
        sum += grade; 
        }
    }
std::cout << sum << std::endl;

input.close(); 
}
```

And I'm kind of stuck because it's only reads numbers from last column. And I dont know what to do further

Comment: This looks a bit strange: `for (std::istringstream stream(line); stream >> word;);` What do you intend to do with it? Please, have a look at [**demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1dcd4924512da0d5).

Comment: How about this?: [**fixed(?) demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e5ab13b2d384f29)

Comment: A general advise: Please, learn how to use a debugger. Debugging your program step-by-step may have helped to uncover your issue yourself. Debugging is an essential skill for software programming.

Comment: Works fine , but is there anyway to  delete the first  row ? I mean to  
"ignore" that line  or start reading from second ? As you can see  in sample implementation there's no  first row

Comment: If the first line is always there, you could just do an initial `std::getline()` without doing everything with the extracted string. Alternatively, you could use `input.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')`. ([std::istream::ignore()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore))

Comment: I have last question because I  almost finished this code but have last issue with  the arithmetic average. So problem is that  its writing my last  column , how to  make arithemtic average from previous  columns ?  here's code : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d89fa90332ab338b               @Scheff